# enable Vue Devtools inspection in laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I want to start using Vue in my laravel 5.4 app. Without laravel i can see vue devtools inspection tab on chrome. But in my laravel app the Vue tab is not there in chrome console although the chrome vue devtool extension says Vue.js is detected.

How can i enable the Vue devtool inspection in my laravel app?

I tried

```
Vue.config.debug = true;
Vue.config.devtools = true;
```

on my app.js file but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: restart your app sometimes I get the same issue

Comment: I have been restarting my app for a zillion times now...well if i were using a CDN then it is suggested that i should use the development version of vue. Is there something similar with laravel? my packages.json file has this: <br /> `"vue": "^2.1.10"`

Comment: Are you using frames? Vue devtools will not look inside iframes for Vues. Also, if using stealth mode, you need to explicity give the extension permission.

Comment: No i am not using frames. Also how do i go about giving permission to the extension? @bbsimonbb

Comment: Chrome menu => More tools => Extensions => Vue dev tools. The box to tick should be on the left under the text. The permission only applies for stealth mode.

Answer (score 0):

try to re-populate vuejs preset:

```
php artisan preset vue
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: I have no idea why it does or doesn't work. I just shared example which  solved my issue. I hope this helps someone else.