# Vue devtools won't display in Laravel Mix app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, laravel-mix

I'm having trouble enabling the Vue dev tools in my fairly new Laravel app.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692009/enable-vue-devtools-inspection-in-laravel-5-4) but I don't want to reset my project which I believe that command does.

I'm also not able to remove the production tip

When I `window.Vue.config` in the console, I get the following:

```
{
   ...
   devtools: true
   productionTip: false
}
```

My `reasources/assets/js/index.js` reads:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

window.Vue.config.productionTip = false
window.Vue.config.devtools = true

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

import App from './App.vue'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App />'
});
```

Despite all of this, the changes aren't reflected in the actual dev tools UI

Comment: Do you run Vue inside an iframe or something? That is a known problem...

Comment: No just anchored on a div in the body. For what it's worth it's in the welcome.blade.php file that comes with the base install

Comment: Can you try `npm run watch` and see if anything is loading in Vue Devtools?

Comment: Well it seems to have fixed itself (ie. I was doing something wrong before) over the weekend. It's now giving me devtools with `npm run watch`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of on the imported `Vue`, set those variables on the resulting `app` object. This works in both Vue 2 and 3 like the following:

```js
const app = new Vue({…});  // vue 2
const app = createApp({…});  // vue 3

window.app = app;
// optionally:
window.app.config.productionTip = false;
window.app.config.devtools = true;
```